# Ada GPS IDE can't seem to find GtkAda

Tags: ide, path, dependencies, ada, gnat

I have installed both the GNAT Programming Studio (GPS) and GtkAda. They both seem to work fine, but when I try to build the Simple Window project under New Project from Template, I get a bunch of errors saying "file gtk.ads not found." This seems to be a directory/dependency sort of problem - GPS doesn't know where to look for GtkAda. I'm running Windows 7, and have GPS installed at C:\GNAT\2011, and GtkAda installed at C:\GtkAda. I tried adding GtkAda to my PATH; at the moment my PATH user variable includes C:\GNAT\2011\bin, and my Path System variable includes C:\GtkAda\bin. Any advice on resolving this problem is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Cross posted to [comp.lang.ada:GPS and GTK Options](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ada/browse_thread/thread/425d51d43921b223).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two things here.

First, "project" is key. Whenever you're building something that depends
on a library like GtkAda, it's much much easier if (a) you use GNAT
Project to manage it, and (b) you use the GPR(s) provided by the library
- always assuming it does, of course.

In the case of GtkAda, that means that your GPR needs to "with" GtkAda;

```
with "gtkada";
project Tinkering is
   ...
```

Second, gnatmake or gprbuild needs to be able to find `gtkada.gpr`.

The easiest way is to install GtkAda in such a way that `gtkada.gpr` is in
the default place that gnatmake/gprbuild expect to find GPR files. This
is `$prefix/lib/gnat`. GtkAda obeys this convention, so you could install 
GtkAda under the same root as your compiler. I don't know why that's not recommended anyway.

If you don't want to do that, you can add the correct location to the
environment variable `ADA_PROJECT_PATH`, for example in your case set it
to `C:\GtkAda\lib\gnat`.

There is a lot of good stuff in the GtkAda README at [libre.adacore.com](http://libre.adacore.com), and in
the [GtkAda User's Guide](http://www.adacore.com/wp-content/files/auto_update/gtkada-docs/gtkada_ug/gtkada_ug.html) which I see from the README is also included with the
installed package at (in your case) `C:\GtkAda\doc\GtkAda\gtkada_ug`.